# Check for Numeric Value in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to check if a database field contains a numeric value in it.  Here is some pseudo code:

```
if {myField} is numeric
    // do something
else
    // do something else
```

I'm looking for a function that will allow me to do the check '{myField} is numeric'.

To help, here are some possible values for {myField} and what the result should be:

```
{myField} = ''          returns false
{myField} = 'abc123'    returns false
{myField} = '123abc'    returns false
{myField} = '123'       returns true
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using Crystal Syntax

```
NumericText({field})  //Returns a Boolean
```

Using Basic Syntax

```
IsNumeric({field})  //Returns a Boolean
```

Comment: @Remus...No problem..glad I could help.