# TryParse or Try/Catch equivalent in Crystal Reports?

Tags: error-handling, crystal-reports, type-conversion

I have created a report in Crystal Reports which takes a text column and splits it based on a delimiter, then the first part of the array is converted to number, the second part converted to date. We have some bad data which isn't converting and is causing the report to crash, and I'd like to create another report to help find the bad data. This report will show all the records that couldn't be parsed in the other report.

I'm predominantly a .Net developer, and we have the wonderful ability to do things like DateTime.TryParse(string) which returns a boolean. I need to be able to do something similar in a Crystal Reports formula field, but for the life of me I cannot find an equivalent, or any kind of try/catch error handling.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is the TryParse equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071098/check-for-numeric-value-in-crystal-reports

Comment: Thank you, nunzabar, that answered my question. I see there is also an isDate function.

Answer (score 0):

**Handling Exceptions for the Crystal Report Engine**

When you run Crystal Reports through your application, there may be times when the Crystal Report Engine causes an exception. When an exception occurs, it can cause an error dialog to appear or cause reports to stop processing. Some of the causes of an exception are:

- The Report Engine is unable to connect to the database. This can be
  because a database location or incorrect logon parameters have been
  passed to the Report Engine. It can also be because of other database
  errors such as the table being locked by another user, the database
  engine being improperly installed, or the table being corrupt.
- Incorrect data has been passed to a parameter. If a parameter
  receives incorrect data from code or from user input, it can cause
  the report to stop running. For example, a string value passed to a
  numeric parameter will stop the report from running.
- An error is found in a Crystal Reports formula. If one of the
  formulas in the report cannot be properly evaluated, an exception
  will be thrown. This can be due to incorrect syntax in the formula or
  another programmatic error, such as a divide by zero error.
- The Report Engine failed to open a report. This can happen if an
  incorrect file name or path is given, a non-Crystal report is
  selected, or the report has been corrupted.

You may choose to let the Crystal Report Engine handle the exception itself, and display its own error message, or you may decide to handle the exception yourself. Some of the advantages of handling the exceptions programmatically are:

- You can customize the error message displayed to the user. For
  example, instead of displaying "Logon failed" when the report cannot
  connect to the data source, you can display a more complete message,
  like "Unable to connect to database, incorrect logon parameters
  provided". This will give the user more detailed information.
- You can write an event to your application's log file. You may choose
  to write the error message, error id, the time it occurred, and other
  relevant information to the log file. This will allow errors to be
  tracked and reviewed later.
- You can handle the exception with your own code to allow the report
  to continue processing. By checking to see what the error is, you may
  be able to write code that handles the error and re-runs the report
  with the correct information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288423%28v=vs.71%29.aspx