# Left most processing in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

We have a data column, that if the first 2 are alpha and the last is alpha, and the 3-7 are numerical, that is what we want. If this is not the case,then we want to display a blanks.

For now if i can get just the first letter as alpha (from what i have seen either its' good or its not) for testing just the first is ok. but this is not compiling.

```
left({vwGenPatInfo.Prim_Policy_Certificate_No},1) in ["A" to "Z"] then ({vwGenPatInfo.Prim_Policy_Certificate_No})
else ' '
```

Comment: should be able to use isnumeric to identify http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071098/check-for-numeric-value-in-crystal-reports

Answer (score 0):

use isnumeric

[Check for Numeric Value in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071098/check-for-numeric-value-in-crystal-reports)

```
if isnumeric(field) = 0 then "not numeric"
else "numeric"
```